# What's the Yoyo progression in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I'm playing Terraria on PC, Expert mode.

Strictly focusing on a Yoyo build, I'm stuck on the Malaise Yoyo for a while. I've killed the Eye of Cthulhu and King Slime with this Yoyo but right now I think it's quite weak in taking down next tier bosses like Skeletron and Queen Bee.

I've taken a look at the wiki but all the next tier yoyos are drops by mobs and I don't like farming hours for a specific yoyo.

Are there any ways to get a more powerful yoyo other than farming mobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are pretty limited. You can get the Amazon, which is a 20 damage yoyo (compared to the Malaise's 16). It can be crafted from materials found in the jungle. The only other alternative is  Code 1, which is randomly sold by the Traveling Merchant (so it's unlikely to show up by the time you progress further).

Every other yoyo requires either Skeletron to be defeated or for Hardmode to have started.

Comment: Is the Amazon worth getting? I see only a damage boost of 4.

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo Well mathematically, compared to what you have now, it's a 25% damage increase.

Answer (score -3):

From the [wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Yoyos)"

- [Wooden Yoyo](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wooden_Yoyo)
- [Rally](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Rally)
- [Malaise](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Malaise)
- [Artery](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Artery)
- [Amazon](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Amazon)
- [Code 1](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Code_1)
- [Valor](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Valor)
- [Cascade](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cascade)

These are all the pre-hardmode yoyos.

Comment: This is a) not in order and b) ignores the OP's parameters